# Unit tests failing to run after app rename due to apple linker error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I recently changed the name of my app and now my unit tests are not running, I am getting an Apple linker error.

Any idea how to fix this?  If I expand my 'Products' folder in Xcode there are 2 files:

MyApp.app
MyAppTests.octest [which appears red]

**Update:**  Deleted all the build folders (derived data) still doesn't work!

> Ld
>   /Users/my/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/srStudio-bdkguonwasdiazelguppliitkdox/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/companyDesignerTests.octest/companyDesignerTests
>   normal i386
>       cd /Users/my/Documents/Working/companyDesigner
>       setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.6
>       setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang
>   -arch i386 -bundle -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk
>   -L/Users/my/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/srStudio-bdkguonwasdiazelguppliitkdox/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F/Users/my/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/srStudio-bdkguonwasdiazelguppliitkdox/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks
>   -F/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator5.0.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks
>   -filelist /Users/my/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/srStudio-bdkguonwasdiazelguppliitkdox/Build/Intermediates/srStudio.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/companyDesignerTests.build/Objects-normal/i386/companyDesignerTests.LinkFileList
>   -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -bundle_loader "/Users/my/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/srStudio-bdkguonwasdiazelguppliitkdox/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/s
>   & r.app" -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -lxml2 -Xlinker
>   -no_implicit_dylibs -D__IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED=50000 -framework CoreData -framework CoreGraphics -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework SenTestingKit -o /Users/my/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/srStudio-bdkguonwasdiazelguppliitkdox/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/companyDesignerTests.octest/companyDesignerTests
>
> ld: in
>   /Users/my/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/srStudio-bdkguonwasdiazelguppliitkdox/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/s
>   & r.app, can't map file, errno=22 for architecture i386 Command
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/clang
>   failed with exit code 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this would help you solve your problem but you could try going to the **organizer** and under **Projects** tab hit **remove** for all *Derived Data*

Answer (score 8):

The following solution works for me:

-> Select your project

-> Select your projectTest file from TARGETS

-> In Host Application, select your project if it shows custom

Comment: This worked for me. But I needed to change variable TEST_HOST in test target of your app (in build settings). There was old application name

Comment: Perfect, this did it for me too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had the similar issue after performing app rename. I'm running Xcode 8.x and what I did was:

1) Project -> Targets -> xxTests -> General -> Enable 'Allow testing Host Application APIs'.

2) Perform clean & rebuild

3) In [Simulator], reset it: Simulator -> Reset Content and Settings...

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issues when renaming my app. You should try with a fresh clean build. Make sure that you remove all build folders (performing a clean in XCode sometimes is not enough).

Answer (score 0):

For the current version of Xcode, you just need to click on the project, then change the name in the file inspector. Or you can right-click on project, and there will be a "Renaming a project" in the help dialog.

Answer (score 0):

I've worked out a resolution to this issue which I've shared here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30508062/233602

I have filed this as http://www.openradar.me/21139630 and rdar://21139630 with Apple. Feel free to dupe if you also experience this issue.