# Where are the app's build folders located?

Tags: xcode

Where are the app's build folders located?  I cannot see anything in the app directory.

Comment: Care to be any more specific? What language? etc.

Comment: Are you asking for `app` build folder when a project is compiled with Xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you create the build in XCode, press Command+7 to view the Log. The log will display the exact path where the final .app file will be located.

Something like the string below;

```
Touch /Users/macmini15/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-ciynarecplxqjqdpmuonamtecgvn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/test.app
    cd /Users/macmini15/Desktop/test
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /usr/bin/touch -c /Users/macmini15/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/test-ciynarecplxqjqdpmuonamtecgvn/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/test.app
```

Comment: Why can I not navigate here through finder?  It seems to be invisible!  I had to go through organizer

Comment: @TheLearner - If you are on Lion the ~/Library folder is now by default hidden. See Oliver Cooper's answer for the quick way to get there.

Comment: Thanks mate - please see my other question related to this, I tried deleting all the derived data but no luck:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9700599/unit-tests-failing-to-run-after-app-rename-due-to-apple-linker-error

Answer (score 6):

Build folder is located in Derived Data folder. You can open this folder through Organizer on Project tab.

Answer (score 3):

In Xcode, on the left hand side where it lists your files, right click on your app (e.g. 'MyApplication.app' and click on 'Show in Finder'.

Hope this helps.