# How to rename XCode5 project that has an attached Pods?

Tags: xcode5, project, rename, cocoapods

I'm trying to rename an XCode5 project that has an attached CocoaPods (Pods project).

(I've attached the CocoaPods using the following tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/12139/introduction-to-cocoapods)

I've tried the standard renaming technique: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19442868/173623

But it breaks the build, since the rename only takes place for App project.

How can I accomplish this task?

Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After viewing your provided tutorial, I would like to suggest you the following:

- First follow the standard renaming technique that you got in another post
- Now if you have enough time and patience, then it'd be best to start over from the section `Installing Your First Dependency`

If you don't do that, then you may follow the next steps, but I can't guarantee for success.

- `Replace` all the occurrence of `CocoaPodsExample.xcworkspace` with `<NEW_PROJ_NAME>.xcworkspace` in the `Pods` folder and possible places
- Close the Xcode project (if you had it open) and open `<NEW_PROJ_NAME>.xcworkspace` to continue and test if it worked
- Now, switch to `ViewController.m` and replace `CocoaPodsExample` with `<NEW_PROJ_NAME>` if exists

Thats it! The project should now build successfully.

Answer (score 4):

I found the easy way to do it:

1. change inside podfile project name.
2. pod install
3. open generated file xcworkspace
   reload red files

Done!

Answer (score 3):

I have just written a [blog post](http://h4ckish.com/2015/01/22/renaming-your-cocoapods-ios-project/) on how to go about this. The most sure-fire procedure looks like:

1. remove CocoaPods
2. rename project
3. re-add CocoaPods to your project

Consult the post for details.

Answer (score 2):

I removed all cocoapods from my project with this GEM

https://github.com/kylef/cocoapods-deintegrate

then renamed my app in standard way and after fixing this issue with tests:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27558736/1237542

everything worked OK.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and used Wassif's answer, however it didn't work until I also selected the new executable (.app) file in Products > Scheme > Edit Scheme > Info

Also I couldn't find "Installing Your First Dependency" on CocoaPods.